# ¿Como puedo imprimir campos separados por un delimitador en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con este ejercicio? Es el siguiente

Escribir un programa, que dado un archivo de texto, un delimitador (puede ser / o * o - ), y una lista de campos, imprima solamente esos campos, separados por ese delimitador.

Ejemplo:

Al usuario le preguntaran que delimitador quiere usar. Puede ser * por ejemplo.
Al usuario también le preguntaran que campos está buscando. Por ejemplo. El usuario quiere que encuentre "ana" en un archivo (*txt*) que ya existe.

Supongamos que en el archivo `.txt` en la primera linea dice:

*"La sotana del padre asustó a la oveja y su lana se erizó"*

Entonces el programa imprimirá:

*ana*ana*

Por ahora llevo esto:

```py
from io import *
archivo1 = open("texto1.txt","r")
deli=input("Que delimitador quieres utilizar? ")
palabra = input("Escriba la palabra que quieras buscar: ")
```

Comment: Que has intentado? Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: He estructurado mejor la pregunta y añadí lo que llevo.

Answer (score 1):

La funcion `split` sobre una `str` crea una lista de elementos, utilizando como delimitador lo que tú quieras. Digamos que crea una **division**.

```
cosa = "esto,es,un,ejemplo"
cosa_dividida = cosa.split(",")
# NOTA: cosa_dividida es ahora ["esto", "es", "un", "ejemplo"]
```

Y la función `join` hace exactamente lo contrario; crea una `str` desde una lista, usando los carácteres que queramos en cada unión. En este caso la usaremos para añadir un salto de linea entre cada **unión**.

```
print("\n".join(cosa_dividida))

>>> esto
>>> es
>>> un
>>> ejemplo
```

Ahora, con tu código... yo haría algo así.

```
delimiter = input("Que delimitador quieres utilizar? ")  # Obtenemos limitador
palabra = input("Escriba la palabra que quieras buscar: ")  # Obtenemos palabra
with open("texto1.txt","r") as archivo:  # Abrimos el archivo, with lo cerrará automáticamente
    for division in archivo.read().split(delimiter):  # Dividimos el archivo según nuestro delimitador
        if palabra in division:  # Por cada elemento en la lista que nos ha creado, si la palabra que queremos que aparezca, aparece...
            print(palabra)  # La imprimimos
```

Ese código es MUY mejorable, pero de esta manera se explica mejor. El código imprimirá la palabra que quieres cada vez que la encuentre en un elemento. Y el archivo entero ha sido dividido en elementos según el delimitador que le des.